# HTML Export of LaTeX Equations Inside Containers

Tags: org-mode

While still using `mathjax` as the primary LaTeX renderer for equations, is
there some switch or function available to also place all equations (both inline
and those between `\begin` and `\end`) inside a `div` container, possibly with a
custom CSS class for additional styling?